# How to find the right keymap to change on addon registration?

Tags: scripting, shortcut

I tried to redefine a shortcut in my addon registration step, but I can't find which one to change. In the user one (`bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.user.keymaps['3D View'].keymap_items`) there are 3 `transform.translate` keymaps.

How can my registration code recognise the one in transform modal map and rebind it to a custom key ? How to restore it in the *unregister* function ?

Comment: See the [api reference](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/info_tutorial_addon.html?#keymap)

Comment: That's exactly what I followed, but there is nothing about modal map there or am I blind ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you after one of these, e.g. rotate?

```
>>> C.window_manager.keyconfigs.user.keymaps['Transform Modal Map'].keymap_items[5].propvalue
'ROTATE'
```

I'm pretty sure there's only one modal map for all transform operators (and not changable with python).

```
import bpy
wm = bpy.context.window_manager
keymap = [k for k in wm.keyconfigs.user.keymaps['Transform Modal Map'].keymap_items if k.type == 'G'] #k.propvalue=="TRANSLATE"]
modal_translate = keymap[0] if len(keymap) > 0 else None
print("\n", modal_translate)
for attr in dir(modal_translate):
    if not attr.startswith("_"):
        val = getattr(modal_translate, attr)
        if type(val) in {int, float, str, bool}:
            print("\t", attr, "=", val)

"""
 <bpy_struct, KeyMapItem("")>
         active = True
         alt = False
         any = False
         ctrl = False
         id = 5
         idname =
         is_user_defined = False
         is_user_modified = False
         key_modifier = NONE
         map_type = KEYBOARD
         name =
         oskey = False
         propvalue = TRANSLATE
         shift = False
         show_expanded = False
         type = G
         value = PRESS
"""
```

But note that you can't provide an operator name in modal maps. Only the predefined modal operations can be set (`propvalue`).

Comment: When I change the shortcut for translate in modal mode under the user preferences, one of the 3 above-mentionned transform.translate go away. So I'm sure I could do it with python by rebinding one of them. problem is which one and how to ensure it works by all users (even those with non-default config).

Comment: Not sure how to safely restore a user binding, since blender doesn't call unregister() on quit nor are save_pre / save_post app handlers called (although blender saves to quit.blend). Probably safer to just deactivate an existing keymap and search for it on unregister() to activate again. This way, you don't have to store anything.

Comment: Entering the code above, i get : >>> modal_translate.type
'WHEELUPMOUSE'. I try to configure G in translate modal mode to cancel blender's translate in my register addon function (to automatically make a GG shortcut)

Comment: Updated code to look for 'G' keybinding and print info. Condition can easily be changed. You should probably look for all `map_type == KEYBOARD` keymap items with `propvalue == 'TRANSLATE'` and set `active=False`. Then add your own new keymap item with `propvalue='CANCEL'`.