# How can I modify the Default Blender Keymap within my Add-on module registration code?

Tags: python, customization

Consider the following script block:

```
import bpy
wm = bpy.context.window_manager    # get window manager
_defaultkm = wm.keyconfigs.default.keymaps    # get default keymap

# try retrieving the keymap_item for the view3d.move operator
# unfortunately, keymap_items at register() time is always empty
_move = _defaultkm['3D View'].keymap_items.get('view3d.move')
_move.active = False    # disable that item
```

It's purpose is to disable a specific shortcut which is shipped with Blender. If you run this in the Text Editor within a Blender session, it works as I wished and disables one of the standard keymap items.

However, my issue is that I'd like to run that code within the `register()` function of an Add-on. Within that function, `_defaultkm` will hold a valid Python object, but `keymap_items` contains no items at all and `get()` always returns `None`, causing the last line of the code to fail. It's worth noting that this fails on all different tricks of retrieving keymaps (such as the one mentioned [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4832/how-to-find-the-right-keymap-to-change-on-addon-registration)), it seems as if I can only access my own Add-on keymaps from within the module registration code.

Is there a way to circumvent this?

## Edit

I tried a solution using a persistent frame change handler, hooked up to the `load_post` event. Still, I was unable to access and change the keymap from there, the issue is the same.

Comment: Not 100% sure what your issue is, started from scratch and it's working well. I can enable and disable `Shift`+`MMB` as expected: https://gist.github.com/p2or/fea39e610552b80b40533fc99934b772

Comment: @p2or Thanks for your gist, it works indeed as expected. However, if I copy/paste it into my own add-on, the keymap again is reported as empty. The only fundamental difference I can make out is that my add-on is a multifile one, which registers itself using `register_module(__name__)`. Your solution might still be working for me, as I can put an extra add-on into the startup section, so it auto-loads.

Comment: @p2or ok, it's not the multifile thing. With your add-on, I get the same error. It works when the user activates it in the Add-ons manager, but if you hit `Save User Settings`, close Blender and re-open, the same issue arises.

Comment: @p2or the error message is Exception in module register(): 'D:\\_PREFS_REFACTOR_\\_REFACTOR_\\scripts\\addons\\blender-deactivate-shift-MMB.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\blender-git\build_windows_Full_x64_vc15_Release\bin\Release\2.80\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 363, in enable
    mod.register()
  File "D:\_PREFS_REFACTOR_\_REFACTOR_\scripts\addons\blender-deactivate-shift-MMB.py", line 21, in register
    wm.keyconfigs.default.keymaps['3D View'].keymap_items['view3d.move'].active = False
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "view3d.move" not found'

Comment: Yeah you are right, `KeyMap("3D View")` collection is empty for whatever reason . However, you can overwrite the existing one by assigning `view3d.rotate` operator: https://gist.github.com/p2or/0969e9981aeec63551e8f0b02e0c7d55 (to make it work at least) @aliasguru.

Comment: @p2or Maybe you can wrap your findings into an answer? I think it's worth summarizing for others what the current possibilities are, pretty sure I'm not the only one trying something like this.

Comment: Thanks @aliasguru, I will if no one else come up with a better idea... Came back to it yesterday, but I still can't figure out at which point in time the collection is filled up during the launch. If that's an option, I think your best bet is providing an additional preset in the keyconfigs `..blender/2x/presets/keyconfig`, which is essentially the same like before (adding a new shortcut to overwrite the existing one) and enabling it along with the addon. Out of curiosity: Does the overwrite work for you?

Comment: @p2or I'm still investigating it. For 2.79 it works no problem, in fact that's how I worked around it before. But for 2.80 there is the new Click-Drag behavior, and here I'm getting issues with overwriting the existing definition. It works, but randomly. Sometimes yes, sometimes no. Since the bug tracker is still closed, I can't go down that route at the moment.

Comment: @p2or Overwriting the definition doesn't work in 2.8. I still get the random behavior with the mappings. The answer is still appreciated, as for 2.79 it works just fine. The bounty expires in three hours by the way.

Comment: Just tested the latest gist with the today build (for windows) and I don't get any glitches or something. I'd like to help but it still works at a first glance. Can you elaborate? Do you mind sharing your current code? Thanks for that reminder, I need to work the next hours and will come back to it at the weekend so better answer it yourself if you don't want to waste your rep @aliasguru

Comment: @p2or You can checkout malias for Blender at https://bitbucket.org/aliasguru/malias-blender/src/2.8/ - make sure to pull the 2.8 branch. The file to look at is Preferences.py, in line 118 I define the enum value for click-drag behavior. In line 155 I try to redefine the view3d.dolly operator, but still I don't get my click-drag Pie Menus with `Ctrl + Shift + MMB`. See `Ctrl + Shift + LMB` for a reference of what I want. The glitch happens on the RMB. In the Addon-Prefs, make sure to enable 'force left select'.

Comment: Access is denied when I try to create a pull request so you can find a refactor of your keymaps as well as the default viewport navigation disabled (via overwrite) to get maya like interaction [here](https://gist.github.com/p2or/521042836e0ab14a2f912031dd0d1e32). I had serios problems to read your code so I refactored `DefineKeymap` function in the first place and added all required parameters to `keymap_items.new`. The thing is that `CLICK_DRAG` is just a new option (probably for pies), what does not mean it's a full replacement, so you can have both. Does that work for you? @aliasguru

Comment: @p2or Thanks for the attempt. Unfortunately, it yields the exact same result. The only real code difference is that you were using the keyword arguments, while my codebase - rather old - uses the positional argument structure still. I'll adapt to yours for better readability, but the problem persists. I'll freeze development on the Add-on anyways now, as the Devs stated that the API will undergo further changes. If after that there is still no solution, I have to provide a custom keymap that users need to import.

Comment: See line [154-160](https://gist.github.com/p2or/521042836e0ab14a2f912031dd0d1e32#file-malias-preferences-dev-py-L154-L160) - The *only real* difference is that I use `PRESS` instead of `CLICK_DRAG` to overwrite the shortcuts no matter if 2.8 or not @aliasguru, works for me as expected in 2.79 as well as in 2.8...

Comment: @p2or Are you sure you've reset your keymap to Default before enabling the Add-on? Because it simply doesn't work here, right MMB Pie menu spawns occasionally, middle MMB pie menu not at all. Same glitch as before. As soon as I uncheck the Lasso Select keymap item in the user prefs - the one which is supposed to be overridden - the pie menu works. Again, thanks for your support, but I'm dropping the matter until there is a stable state of the Python API reached.

Comment: Yep, 100% sure @aliasguru. Just tested the patch with the today build without any issues, I get maya like navigation as well as the lasso select operator when the addon is enabled for `mmb` or `shift+mmb`. As a precaution I removed my appdata folder beforehand. If the keyconfig comes along with an addon there is nothing to reset within the *Input Tab* of the *User Preferences*. Notice that a restart is required if you reset your keyconfig. Question is: What did I forget to test?

Comment: @p2or I think I understand now, we've not been testing the same thing. The non-working hotkey is `Ctrl + Shift + RMB-drag` and `Ctrl + Shift + MMB-drag`. It *should* spawn a custom pie menu, but with the MMB I get the Dolly operator, and the RMB *sometimes* results in Lasso Deselect.

Comment: I always thought you've got issues on how to disable the hotkeys to get something like maya. Anyway, in this case you just need to add the other type as well, see [my new revision](https://gist.github.com/p2or/521042836e0ab14a2f912031dd0d1e32). Both pies are now working in *Object* and *Edit Mode* right? @aliasguru

Comment: @p2or Yes, this one is working. The reason why I was asking the question as I did was that I wanted the Pie Menus to only spawn on a CLICK_DRAG event. If there is a PRESS event for the same key binding defined already, it takes precedence over the Add-on. If the PRESS event is also overwritten by the Add-on, it works. If there is a collision between two CLICK-DRAG definitions, the behavior is a random one. Still some headaches until 2.8 is final  :)

Comment: Can confirm. `CLICK_DRAG` does not appear in the new info area at the bottom so I also think that's still unfinished... and I also think that the deactivation of all the c-operators (like `view3d.move`) by any addon is design-wise restricted so we are only allowed to overwrite the hotkeys @aliasguru

Comment: Hi guys. What if a keymap item has multiple entries, like 'view3d.manipulator', for example? @p20r's code will deactivate the first manipulator keymap entry but not the remaining two. How are the rest of them accessed?

Comment: @andyV The trick is that it's not the keymap item (or more precisely, the operator) which is being overwritten, it's the hotkey itself. So if there is more than one occurance, you'll need to override the other hotkeys as well, just let them execute something else to deactivate the default one.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems when tried to modify default key maps with python.
The keymap_items collection was empty at startup script but after the start, items were accessible.

The problem was solved using thread and time.sleep
It is not the best approach but working..

The load_post handler didn't work for application start but worked for file open.

I didn't find any "start_post" handler method.

here is the first code (startup scripts folder):

```
import bpy

wm = bpy.context.window_manager
kc = wm.keyconfigs.default
km = kc.keymaps['Screen Editing']
print('item count:',len(km.keymap_items))

#> "item count: 0"
```

here is the solved version

```
import bpy,_thread,time


wm = bpy.context.window_manager
kc = wm.keyconfigs.default
km = kc.keymaps['Screen Editing']


def thrd_func():
    time.sleep(.1)
    print('item count:',len(km.keymap_items))

_thread.start_new_thread(thrd_func,())


#> "item count: 12"
```

and with handler

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def hand_func(arg):
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.default
    km = kc.keymaps['Screen Editing']
    print('item count:',len(km.keymap_items))

bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(hand_func)
```