# Overriding a default keymap?

Tags: scripting, add-on, keymap

I'm trying to add a keymap that overrides an actual shortcut in Blender (`M` key in Grease Pencil's Draw Mode).

By default, `M` triggers:
[image]

I would like to add my own action (opening a panel) in that same key. The code I have:

```
addon_keymaps = []

def _register_hotkey():
    # Add the hotkey
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        name = 'Grease Pencil Draw'
        space_view = 'VIEW_3D'
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name=name, space_type=space_view)
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new("wm.call_panel", type='M', value='PRESS')
        kmi.properties.name = "TEST_PT_my_panel"  
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))
```

But I had no luck, `M` triggers that `gpencil.draw`.

Also, I'm not sure if I'm doing it propperly. I'm not sure if that name I'm entering is the correct and I dont know what it refers to (to be honest, [the API says nothing about it](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.6/bpy.types.KeyMaps.html#bpy.types.KeyMaps)). So I don't know if it can be any name, if it must match the name of the keymap I want to override (if so, which is its name? 'Grease Pencil Draw'? 'Grease Pencil Stroke Paint (Draw brush)'?).

Also, Im not fully sure if is possible.

I'm calling `_register_hotkey()` in:

```
bpy.app.handlers.load_post
```

(Since I read [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/131268/66816) that when loading the keymaps are not accesible, just to be sure. But I got the same result like when Im calling `_register_hotkey()` in `register()`)

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: If this addon is meant to be shared and used by other people, I would advise against replacing keymap entries. Though obviously if it's only for you, it's fair game :) In any case, I think [this might help](https://blenderartists.org/t/removing-a-specific-default-hotkey-shortcut-via-a-script/1163540/2?u=l0lock)

Comment: @L0Lock Thank you so much for the help friend, worked perfectly! Also, I think you are totally right, but at the same time, the original operator (gpencil.draw) seems weird (at least for me). Is like it stops the input until you click/draw again. I really don't know which uses could it have, to be honest (seems like a good thing to call from code, but not from the UI).

Again, thank you so much for the help, much appreciated :)

Comment: My pleasure. I posted an answer with just a quote from my link for good form, feel free to edit it to make it better if you want or post your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the solution from the blenderartists forum:

> The default keymap often isn’t accessible during addon registration, so you probably need to add a timer.
>
> Note: This example only checks for kmi entries that matches the `kmi.idname`, so if you used something like `wm.call_pie_menu` it would disable every entry, unless you added a conditional based off from the kmi operator property.
>
> ```py
> def disable_default_kmi(km=None, idname=None, retries=10):
>     wm = bpy.context.window_manager
>
>     if not (km and idname) or retries < 1:
>         return
>
>     # the default keyconfig
>     kc = wm.keyconfigs['blender']
>     for kmi in kc.keymaps[km].keymap_items:
>         if kmi.idname == idname:
>             kmi.active = False
>             print("Disabled", kmi.name)
>             return
>
>     print("Retrying..")
>     # add some delay
>     bpy.app.timers.register(
>         lambda: disable_default_kmi(km, idname, retries - 1),
>         first_interval=0.1)
> ```
>
> Then during `register()` you can run something like this.
>
> ```py
> def register():
>     ...
>     disable_default_kmi('Screen Editing', 'screen.area_options')
> ```
>
> ---
>
> *Source: [Removing a specific default hotkey / shortcut via a script? - Coding / Python Support - Blender Artists Community](https://blenderartists.org/t/removing-a-specific-default-hotkey-shortcut-via-a-script/1163540/2?u=l0lock)*

Visit the source for more.